# How to use ctypes argtypes c_ubytes for unsigned char *?

Tags: python, c++, ctypes

I'm new to Python and I'm trying to use C++ module as AES library: http://spaniakos.github.io/AES/classAES.html    : AES.h. 
It contains a module with byte defined as unsigned char:

```
void AES::set_IV(unsigned long long int IVCl){
    memcpy(iv,&IVCl,8);
    memcpy(iv+8,&IVCl,8);
    IVC = IVCl;
}

 void AES::get_IV(byte *out){
    memcpy(out,&IVC,8);
    memcpy(out+8,&IVC,8);
}
 void AES::iv_inc(){
    IVC += 1;
    memcpy(iv,&IVC,8);
    memcpy(iv+8,&IVC,8);
}
```

I've tried some code to use it in Python:

```
from ctypes import *
import ctypes
import numpy
import glob

libfile = glob.glob('build/*/AES.so')[0]
mylib = ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary(libfile)

x = c_ulonglong(22222222)
y = numpy.ctypeslib.as_array(x)
iv = (c_ubyte * 16)()
my_iv = (ctypes.c_ubyte * 16)(0)

pointer_type =ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_ubyte)
pointer = ctypes.cast(my_iv, pointer_type)

mylib._ZN3AES6set_IVEy.argtypes = [numpy.ctypeslib.ndpointer(dtype = ctypes.c_ulonglong)]
mylib._ZN3AES6set_IVEy.restype = None
mylib._ZN3AES6set_IVEy(y)  # the set_IV C++ func
mylib._ZN3AES6iv_incEv.restypes = None
mylib._ZN3AES6iv_incEv()   # the iv_inc C++ func
print("OK")
mylib._ZN3AES6get_IVEPh.argtypes =[(pointer_type)]
mylib._ZN3AES6get_IVEPh(pointer)   # the get_IV C++ func
print("OK")
```

and the result is: [enter image description here][1]
It means that the first two functions have run completely but the last Segmentation Fault means something wrong occurred. I've searched this online but still doesnt have any idea about this. 
In addition, I do code with python3 on raspberry pi.
    Could you tell me about this problem?
    Thanks.

```
  [1]:
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jb3e3.png

Comment: *CTypes* stands for ***C*** (**not *C++***) types. You should look for other options (*PyBind11*, *Cython*, *SWIG*, ...).

Comment: Sorry, It's my bad. I will review your suggested options. Thanks for your help.
But could you tell me that why 2 above functions could run normally? I tried and It ran.

Comment: Probably bvecause *C++* pointers are the same as *C* ones (simply addresses). If you only need that it might work (although it's not recommended), but if you want to go deeper, that's when the problems start.

Comment: OK, I see. 
Thank you Cristi.

Comment: who can give a pybind11 py::buffer_info example?